# Hide modal WinForms control linked by dialog result

Tags: winforms, modal-dialog

I have:

1. Running application
2. RuleSetForm started from main application
3. CustomPropertyForm started from RuleSetForm

I need to do outside selection from CustomPropertyForm, get back to it while it's hidden, and eventually click Cancel/OK without affecting RuleSetForm. This is how I call the CustomPropertyForm

```
if (new CustomPropertyForm(this._doc, ref this._ruleSet).ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   // Action
}
```

[image]

I'm subscribed to external event of selecting elements so basically, I need to hide these forms while selecting and unhide them after the selection is completed, without triggering any dialog result on CustomPropertyForm. What I achieve so far is:

```
private void btnSelectElements_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.Hide();
```

and

```
private void CurrentSelection_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.Visible = true;
```

but the issue is when I click on "Select elements..." it will trigger DialogResult and show the RuleSetForm which further is blocking an access to the screen (thus selecting elements).

Any solution for this? Hope I'm clear enough...

Comment: I think it would help if you show more code. For example, the click event for the select elements button and the select elements dialog result code at a minimum. Please don't do brief 1 line code snippets.